# After using the Elasticsearch JDBC Importer, 'asciifolding' is not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch

Using the Elasticsearch JDBC importer with this configuration:

```
bin=/usr/share/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-jdbc-2.1.1.2/bin
lib=/usr/share/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-jdbc-2.1.1.2/lib
echo '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "url" : "ip/db",
        "user" : "myuser",
        "password" : "a7sdf7hsdf8hn78df",
        "sql" : "SELECT title, body, source_id, time_order, type, blablabla...",
        "index" : "importeditems",
        "type" : "item",
        "elasticsearch.host": "_eth0_",
        "detect_json" : false
    }
}' | java \
       -cp "${lib}/*" \
       -Dlog4j.configurationFile=${bin}/log4j2.xml \
       org.xbib.tools.Runner \
       org.xbib.tools.JDBCImporter
```

I've indexed some documents correctly with the form:

```
{
"title":"Tiempo de Opinión: Puede comenzar un ciclo",
"body":"Sebas Álvaro nos trae cada lunes historias y anécdotas de la montaña<!-- com -->",
"source_id":21188,
"time_order":"1438638043:55c2c6bb96d4c"
"type":"rss"
}
```

I'm trying to ignore the accents (for example, `opinión`in title has an **ó**), so if a user searches `"tiempo de opinión"` or `"tiempo de opinion"` with a `match_phrase` it gives a match with the documents with or without accent.

So after using the importer and indexing everything, I changed my index settings to `default`analyzer with an `asciifolding` filter.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/importeditems/_close'

curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/importeditems/_settings?pretty=true' -d '{
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "tokenizer" : "standard",
          "filter":  [ "lowercase", "asciifolding"]
}}}}'

curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/importeditems/_open'
```

Then I make a `match_phrase` to match`"tiempo de opinion"` (no accent) and `"tiempo de opinión"` (with accent)

```
# No accent
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/importeditems/_search?pretty=true' -d'
{
"query": {
            "match_phrase" : {
                 "title" : "tiempo de opinion"
}}}'

# With accent
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/importeditems/_search?pretty=true' -d'
{
"query": {
            "match_phrase" : {
                 "title" : "tiempo de opinión"
}}}'
```

But no match is given when they exist (if I `match_phrase` the phrase `tiempo de` it returns some hits containing `tiempo de opinión`).

I think the problem is due to de JDBC Importer because I reproduced the error without using the importer, adding another index and entries by hand, changing the index settings also to `asciifolding` and everything works as expected. You can see this working example right [**here**](http://pastebin.com/4ApJEtYC).

If I check the settings of the index created after using the importer (`importeditems`)

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/importeditems/_settings?pretty=true'
```

This outputs:

```
{
  "importeditems" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1457533907278",
        "analysis" : {
          "analyzer" : {
            "default" : {
              "filter" : [ "lowercase", "asciifolding" ],
              "tokenizer" : "standard"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "x",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "2010199"
}}}}
```

... and if I check the settings of the manually created index (`test`):

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test/_settings?pretty=true'
```

I get the same exact output:

```
 {
  "test" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1457603253278",
        "analysis" : {
          "analyzer" : {
            "default" : {
              "filter" : [ "lowercase", "asciifolding" ],
              "tokenizer" : "standard"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "x",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "2010199"
    }}}}
```

Can someone please tell why is not working if I use the Elasticsearch JDBC Importer and why is it working if I add raw data?

Comment: Which version of the Elasticsearch JDBC importer are you using?

Comment: `elasticsearch-jdbc-2.1.1.2`, you have also it on the top of the post :P

Comment: If I read that correctly, you changed your mapping settings AFTER indexing all of your data?

Comment: I changed the `settings` of both index (by adding the `default` analyzer), not the `mapping`.

Comment: Hahaha, sorry, I missed. I'm testing this now, let's see if I can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue by *first* changing the `settings` by adding the `analysis` module:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/importeditems/_close'

curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/importeditems/_settings?pretty=true' -d '{
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "tokenizer" : "standard",
          "filter":  [ "lowercase", "asciifolding"]
}}}}'

curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/importeditems/_open'
```

... and then importing all the data again.

It's extrange, because as I stated on the post, I did exactly the same in both cases (with the JDBC Importer and the raw data):

1. Index data
2. Change index `settings`
3. Make the query with `match_phrase`

And it worked with the raw data (`test`) and not with the one I used the importer with (`importeditems`). The only thing I can think about is that the `importeditems` were more than 12GB and it needs time to re-create the content with the `asciifolding` on it. That's why the changes were not reflecting just after the `asciifolding` was *activated*.

**Anyways, if someone is having the same issue and specially for those who are working with a huge amount of data, remember first to set the analyzer, and then index all the data.**

According to the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_controlling_analysis.html):

> Queries can find only terms that actually exist in the inverted index,
>   so **it is important to ensure that the same analysis process is applied
>   both to the document at index time,** and to the query string at search
>   time so that the terms in the query match the terms in the inverted
>   index.